# Download files from web, unknown name of file

Tags: command-line, batch, powershell, automation

I need to download 10-15 programas every week, and looking how to automate the process. It's easy when I know exactly the name of .exe file; but what about the case when I dont?

For example, lets look at malwarebytes at https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/ 
When you open the link in browser it promts you to download the file mbam-setup-2.XXXXX.exe 
The file comes from site: http://data-cdn.mbamupdates.com/v2/mbam/consumer/data/mbam-setup-2.0.4.1028.exe

Now, how can it be downloaded via powershell (or .bat, or whatever, less code, the better) without user interaction? And without changing the script when malwarebyte isues new version.

Comment: Scrape the link on the page to get the current file URL?

Comment: ok, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/):

```
wget  http://downloads.malwarebytes.org/file/mbam/
```